Error al mostrar tabla de inventario procedente de una base de datos
Quiero crear un inventario de usuario propio básico donde se muestre en cada columna lo que corresponde según los datos de mi tabla. Pero cuando mando a imprimir el resultado es el que se muestra en la imagen.
Este es el código de la función, creo que el error está en la consulta a la base de datos:
    def load_products(self):
        current_user_id = MyApp().user_id  # Obtener el ID del usuario autenticado
        if self.user_id:
            query = """
            SELECT p.nombre AS NombreProducto,
                iu.cantidad AS Cantidad,
                p.descripcion AS Descripcion,
                iu.precio_compra AS PrecioCompra,
                p.precio AS PrecioActual
            FROM InventarioUsuario iu
            INNER JOIN Productos p ON iu.producto_id = p.id
            WHERE iu.usuario_id = ?
            """
            self.cursor.execute(query, (self.user_id,))
            
            # Limpiar el GridLayout antes de agregar nuevos productos
            self.grid_layout.clear_widgets()

            # Agregar las cabeceras de las columnas en el orden especificado
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Nombre"))
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Cantidad"))
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Descripción"))
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Precio Compra"))
            self.grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Precio Actual"))

            for row in self.cursor.fetchall():
                box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint_y=None, height=30)
                box_layout.add_widget(Label(text=row.NombreProducto))
                box_layout.add_widget(Label(text=str(row.Cantidad)))
                box_layout.add_widget(Label(text=row.Descripcion))
                box_layout.add_widget(Label(text=str(row.PrecioCompra)))
                box_layout.add_widget(Label(text=str(row.PrecioActual)))
                self.grid_layout.add_widget(box_layout)

            self.conn.close()
        else:
            print("No se encontró el ID del usuario autenticado.")


